# Only match if all characters belong to what is specified

Tags: python, regex

> <sup>*Match*</sup> **3.14529**
>
> <sup>*Match*</sup> **-255.34**
>
> <sup>*Match*</sup> **128**
>
> <sup>*Match*</sup> **1.9e10**
>
> <sup>*Match*</sup> **123,340.00**
>
> <sup>*Skip*</sup> **720p**

In order to skip the last one, I tried this regex:

### `([\d\.e\-,])`

The criteria is this: If every character in the string is either a digit(\d) or a dot(.) or exponent (e) or  negative (-) or a comma(,), match the string, if any other characters are present skip the entire string.

Problem is that the last one has a "p" in it, and it must be ignored. However, due to the digits in front of it (720), it is also included in the match.

Comment: `(\b[([\d\.e\-,]+\b)` Use word boundaries?

Comment: @NightShadeQueen I forgot to mention that using `p$` is a possibility, but is it possible to establish the idea that I mentioned above?

Comment: Your regex allows "eeeeeeee". Do you really want that string? :)

Comment: @gberger Yes, that is fine. as long as there's nothing other the ones I specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using ^ and $ to match the whole string:

`^[\d\.e\-,]+$`

`^` matches the beginning of a string, `$` the end.

Comment: This works as intended. If the start and stop are searching for any of those characters inside the square brackets, shouldn't it match the last one (720p) if I add a digit after "p" (720p5) - It doesn't do this match. Why is that?

Comment: It doesn't because the string has to contain only what's enclosed within `^` and `$`. Anything else will fail the match.

Comment: But it does start with a `7` and ends with a `5` both of which are included in `\d`... I am confused.

Comment: Yes, the `+` matches one or more of the characters within the brackets. :)

Comment: Read the regexp like this: From the start of the string `^`, allow only one or more of `[\d\.\e-,]` to the end of the string `$`.

Comment: @RenaeLider the regex says "match the start of the string, then match any of these characters once or more, then match the end of the string". `"720p5"` matches the start of the string (fine), then any of those characters three times (fine), then the 'p', which fails the `[\d\.e\-,]` so it advances to the next part of the regex, but then to match it has to be at the end of the string, which it isn't - so it fails.

Comment: @ciscoheat this matches too many invalid strings... like `,` or `e,e.,e`, `...`, etc

Comment: @Fede that is fine according to OP. See comments in the question.

Answer (score 3):

You have to leverage anchors `^` and `$`, however if you use:

```
^[\d\.e\-,]+$
```

...this will allow matches like:

```
.e.e.e---,,
1,.2,2e.eee
.....
---
etc...
```

I can come up with this regex:

```
^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.?\d*(e\d*)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/nS8kC9/1)**

[image]

You can use a code like this:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^-?\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.?\d*(e\d*)?$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"Match\n3.14529\n-255.34\n128\n1.9e10\n123,340.00\n\nSkip \n720p"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: I suggest you modify this pattern to `^-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d+)?(?:e\d+)?$` to skip `1.` and `1e`

Comment: @alphabravo thanks for the comment, noticed that question was resolved so, will leave it that way. Thanks again